# MS VSTS How do I view Requirements in a tree

Tags: tree, azure-devops, requirements, workitem

We are in the process of evaluating VSTS as a Requirements/Test Management platform.

Is there a way of viewing Requirements (Or Work Items in General) in a tree structure?

I have tried but can't find any way of doing it.

Cheers

Comment: Have you referred to the documentation on work item queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean map child work items to parents and show the work items in a tree structure, then you can try below ways:

- In **Backlog**:

  You can set `Parents` to `Show` and click the expand `＋` icon to
  expand `one level` of the hierarchy (click twice to expand two
  levels). See [Show parents and expand the tree hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=vsts&tabs=horizontal#show-parents-and-expand-the-tree-hierarchy)
- In **query**:

  Use the tree query (`Tree of work items`) to view a multi-tiered, nested list of work items.
  See [Use a tree query to view hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp#use-a-tree-query-to-view-hierarchies)

[image]

Comment: Thanks haven't touched this for nearly 4 years that was spot on.